# structure of url

Tags: php, url

I have seen on many sites, the structure of the URL is of the form

> `http://tabsize.com`**/user/login**

OR

> `http://tabsize.com`**/user/register**
>
> `http://tabsize.com`**/user/account**

From user->login OR user->register

So how to you maintain this sort of URL structure?

I am currently using hard-coded type URLs like,

> www.example.com/login.php
>
> www.example.com/register.php

I dont think my way is professional, I also want to be able to create the same structure as given in the example above.

How do you achieve it?

Comment: You need to hook into the webserver to achieve this. What webserver are you using? Apache?

Comment: You use Apache's ModRewrite ability.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times here on SO. This highly depends on your server configuration and your code. Please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+url+clean+nice) and look around because with your current questions, an answer would be only a guess. You need to add how you designed your site, how you output URLs, your server configuration and all that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using folders and index files:

```
http://tabsize.com/user/register
->http://tabsize.com/user/register/index.php

http://tabsize.com/user/account
->http://tabsize.com/user/account/index.php
```

Comment: I also thought about that, but for every user added to that site, a new profile is created.
http://tabsize.com/profile/143

how is it done?

Comment: @user478636 `.htaccess` mod_rewrite. You basically map a url like `/profile/143` to something like `profile.php?id=143`

Answer (score 0):

Personaly i using this website, it help's a lot:
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason that you see this structure on many sites is because they use a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework).

And most of the time, `user` corresponds to a module, and `login` to an action. If your  application is big enough, you should consider [using a framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all requests go via your index.php file. That way you can perform a lookup on the path and choose a function to return the response.

eg.

```
index.php?uri=/user/login/
```

then inside you index.php file perform the lookup

```
<?php

$uri = $_GET["uri"];

if ($uri == "/user/login/") {
  print "login page";
}
else if ($uri == "/something/else/") {
  print "some other page";
}
```

This way isn't maintainable and I wouldn't recommend it but you get the idea.

Then in your .htaccess you want to remove index.php?uri=

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?uri=$0 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Now URLs like this will work `http://example.com/user/login/`

I would recommend looking into PHP frameworks which already have solutions to this. CodeIgniter and Kohana are good.

Or Django if you know Python.